# Cannot use Copy on Adobe Payload Request

Tags: debugging, request, adobe-analytics, payload

When testing Adobe beacons, I used to be able to right-click the Request Payload on the Network tab and select "Copy".  It's now disabled.  Does anyone know why?  Is there another took I can use for debugging?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, right after I asked this, my boss told me the answer.  You can no longer double-click the request payload.  Instead you have to select the first and last items then you can copy it.  Cheers!